# Сравнение времени php

Tags: php

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста как сравнить два времени есть допустим время 12:00 и 03:00 если их сравнивать, то 03:00 меньше чем 12:00. Мне нужно сделать как то так, если я указываю 03:00 то что бы считалось что это уже следующий день (сутки) и считало что 03:00 это позже (больше) чем 12:00

Answer (score -1):

Допустим так, не идеальное решение, но рабочее:

```
$start = "12:00";
$end = "03:00";

//Переводим время в метки UNIX
$startUnix = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')." ".$start);
$endUnix = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')." ".$end);

//Считаем разницу между временем
$time = $endUnix - $startUnix;

if($time < 0){

  $endUnix += 86400; //Если 2 время меньше, добавляем 1 сутки(86400 сек) 
  $time = $endUnix - $startUnix;
  echo "Часов: ".$time/(60*60); //Напишет, что между времеными метками 15 часов(след. день)

} else {

  echo "Часов: ".$time/(60*60);

}
```